# Converting output to Excel into LibreOffice

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I've done some search in this forum and couldn't find nothing. I have a lot of programs that have Excel output, some of them using COM-HANDLE resource, others using DDE-EXECUTE resource (yes, it's old, very old ...). Here in my organization, forced by elevated costs of Microsoft licensing, we're doing a migration from Microsoft Office to LibreOffice and, obviously, programs with Excel outputs don't work there.

Is there some way to do a massive conversion of programs who does Excel outputs to LibreOffice outputs or, in a better world, a way to maintain Excel outputs and do a LibreOffice output when Excel isn't installed ?

Thanks in advance.
Bruno

Comment: Without any certain knowledge, I would have thought that the LibreOffice API will not be compatible, and so you'd have to re-write all the COM stuff to use a LibreOffice API, after testing the presence of the Excel application. It's very unlikely there is an automated way of doing this, thus the cost is likely to exceed the saving in licenses. Perhaps prioritise Excel licenses for people who need this functionality. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724050/how-do-i-make-vba-code-compatible-with-libre-office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Excel spreadsheets directly and on any platform without having Excel installed and without using COM or DDE or any of that cruft.

A package that does that can be found here:   http://docxfactory.com/tutorial/

Or you can roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

We use Apache POI for this sort of thing with good results (though it can be picky about the data you give it and if it's not happy, you get the typical 250 line stack trace that gives you no clue at all where you went wrong). No expensive MSFT software required. It's server side so it may or may not suit your circumstances.